# QlikSense try Access to BigQuery - ODBC error

Tags: google-bigquery, qliksense

I am trying to get connection to BigQuery using QlikSense (latest version).
I'm following the step required

```
Qlik Web Connectors (BigQuery) wants to access your Google Account.
```

I get the authorization code

But then I press for validation, I get the error:

```
ODBC Wrapper: Unable to connect to ODBC data source:[Qlik][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key "OAuthApiErr' and component ID 870: Invalid source component ID:870 MessageParameters = ["Couldn't connect to server"]
```

Seems that is something on BigQuery side ... some authorization missing?

Thanks

Get a connection to explore data

Comment: Are you able with the same account to use BigQueries directly from Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: yes I can. I start to get data with Microsoft PowerBI wit success, secondly with Qlik Sense and I get the error. Back again to PowerBI and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you make any change on the Google Cloud Platform side? Change permission on the account which you are using or something like that?

Comment: No, well at least I think.

Comment: seems like Qlik has had similar issues in the past when connecting through ODBC, have you tried using OLE DB connection?

Comment: No, I've not. But I do not know the way to connect using OLE DB connection. I need the db connection string and I do not know how to get it on GCP